# Creating see through (android) app icons

Tags: android, graphics, icons

[image]

How are (android) app icons created? I have attached an example of such an icon. When this is used the just the blue envelope and letter are shown. The grey and white checkboard becomes see through (which is ideal). Could someone please point me as to how these are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PNG picture with transparent background. You can create your own with gimp for exemple.

Comment: Ok. Ive got GIMP, but are there are any basic building blocks somewhere, where these are created from?

Comment: This web site can help you  : [https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none]
If you don't find a good icon, internet have a lot of icon for free.